# Why do I get different arrays by reading the same image using keras data generator and a custom generator

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, data-generation

**Summary:** I wrote a customized flow_from_dataframe to read in images. However, I found that when reading in the same image, (i) the keras data generator and the customized generator printed images which are the same by eyes (ii) but the numpy arrays are different.

**Details:** (i) I wrote a generator and replace the Keras generator by customized generator (all the other code are copy and paste), but I got significantly different results (the one with customized generator has error 5 times larger). That's why I looked into the data two generators prepare.
(ii) To ensure two generators process the same image, I only put one image in the data, therefore batchsize = 1.
(iii) To ensure the color mode is RGB, I used keras.preprocessing.image.load_img.
(iv) I compared images from two generators by observing (look the same), and looking into the numpy arrays (different).

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import keras
import cv2
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

img_size = 256
train_batchsize = 1
df_train = pd.read_csv('data_for_generatorvalidation.csv')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator1 = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df_train,directory=None,
                                          x_col='Image',
                                          y_col=targt_vb,
                                          has_ext=True,
                                          batch_size=train_batchsize,
                                          seed=1,
                                          shuffle=False,
                                          class_mode="raw",
                                          target_size=(img_size, img_size),
                                          color_mode='rgb',
                                          interpolation='nearest'
                                          )
np_imgs1, np_values1 = train_generator1[0]


class DataGenerator3(keras.utils.Sequence):
def __init__(self, dataframe, batch_size, dim, shuffle=True, iftest = False):
    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.dataframe = dataframe.reset_index(drop=True)
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()
    self.iftest = iftest

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(len(self.dataframe) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
    dataframe_temp = self.dataframe.iloc[indexes]

    # Generate data
    X, y = self.__data_generation(dataframe_temp)

    return X, y

def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.dataframe))
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

def __data_generation(self, dataframe_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples'  # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.dim[0], self.dim[1], self.dim[2]), dtype=float)
    X = X.astype('float32')
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=float)
    file_name = []

    dataframe_temp2 = dataframe_temp.reset_index(drop=True)
    for [n_index, vector_row] in dataframe_temp2.iterrows():
        img_row = vector_row.Image
        value_row = vector_row.CI_GHI
        img = load_img(img_row)
        img = img_to_array(img)
        X[n_index,] = img/255.0
        y[n_index] = value_row
        file_name.append(img_row)
    if self.iftest == True:
        return X, y, file_name
    elif self.iftest == False:
        return X, y


params1 = {'batch_size': train_batchsize,
      'dim': (img_size, img_size, 3),
      'shuffle': False,
       'iftest': False}
train_generator2 = DataGenerator3(df_train, **params1)
np_imgs2, np_values2 = train_generator2[0]


for i in range(1):
img1 = np_imgs1[i]
value1 = np_values1[i]

img2 = np_imgs2[i]
value2 = np_values2[i]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.text(.5, 1.1, round(value1, 4), size=20, weight='bold', ha="center",
     transform=ax1.transAxes)
ax1.imshow(img1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
ax2.imshow(img2)
ax2.text(.5, 1.1, round((value2), 4), size=20, weight='bold', ha="center",
     transform=ax2.transAxes)
plt.show()

print(np.array_equal(img1, img2))
```

**Images:** the image input for generators, the images read in by the two generators (values about are just y for the regression problem), and a snapshot of numpy arrays from the two generators (where you can find the differences).

[This is the image input for generators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTl6V.jpg)

[These are images read in by generators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrxzn.jpg)

[These are a snapshot of numpy arrays from the two generators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnK82.jpg)

Comment: Instead of linking to external sites, you can embed images into your post

Comment: Thanks for the note. I currently do not have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Keras at all, but wanted to be sure you are aware that JPEG is lossy. Different encoders (writers) and decoders (readers) make different tradeoffs for accuracy and performance. If you have a Numpy array that you save as JPEG, and then read back in from disk immediately afterwards, it will generally differ. Is it possible to save as lossless PNG?

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell for this point. I didn't even know this before. I assume the same reader (that's why I use keras.preprocessing.image.load_img instead of other functions, such as cv2, PIL, etc., to load in images). I also did a quick check and found the same function (keras.preprocessing.image.load_img) can get the same array by reading in the same image.